# Qt: Blur behind window

Tags: c++, qt, blur

I have 2 widgets:
[image: widgets]

One of them is background(semi-transparent), second contains other widgets(without background)
Can I make a blur behind window like this? 
[image]

Comment: I guess you can hijack the parent's paint event and append a blur in the children's rect and do the alpha blending mormally. For example, sub class the widget's class, re-implement paint event, add to the end: if background is visible, do a blur in the background's rect. Also this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383427/blur-effect-over-a-qwidget-in-qt

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 widgets:
>   One of them is background(semi-transparent), second contains other
>   widgets(without background)

[QLCDNumber](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html) is a widget of such kind.

That is doable and one of the good examples is: [C++,Qt QMainWindow Transparent Background Example](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=191&key=QMainWindowTransparentBg). But if you need to make it semi-transparent or lower the transparency you can do something like:

```
// mind the last component of rgba
mainwindow->setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 127)};");
```