# C++ Qt program design issue

Tags: c++, qt, class-design

In C++ Qt there is a class `QWidget`

- class `A` inherits `QWidget` and adds some features
- class `B` inherits `A` and adds some features
- class `C` inherits `B` and adds some features, `C` must be of type `QWidget` and should do all things done by `B`

For some reason `C` is not behaving as expected, I have to rewrite class `C`. I can not modify code up to class `B` creation.

How can I solve this problem? Any design pattern, or anything else?

If I try to inherit `QWidget` and `B`, a multiple inheritance, there will be two `QWidget` which leads to problem (QObject - moc does not allow it).

If I inherit from `QWidget` and pass object of `B` to `C`'s constructor, whatever operation `B` performs applies to another `QWidget` coming through `B`, which is not desired, all features provided by `B` should apply to my `C`'s `QWidget`.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to have a look at the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).  Additional reference here: [Decorator Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

Comment: ***For some reason C is not behaving as expected*** Maybe you should ask a question about that (showing some details so we can possibly help). Perhaps we can fix it if we know what is the problem.

Comment: ***class C inherits B and adds some feature, C must be of type QWidget and should
do all things done by B*** There really is should be no problem with this. `C` will be a `QWidget` by its parent.

Comment: @drescherjm  The problem is B is doing something with the layout of the Qwidget that it has which make user interface incorrect, and I don't have source of B.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker , I have seen exactly the Decorator Design Pattern, but it does not look like solving my problem.
It says to pass object of one class to another, if I pass object of B to C's constructor, manipulation done by B internally on it's QWidget will persist.

Comment: @Sumit Is it possible to instantiate B as a member of C?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker ,  Yes

Comment: @Sumit So regardless of whether B is passed in to the constructor, or is instantiated as a member, it seems to me that you could (Decorator pattern-style) forward method calls to B untouched that you want to leave alone, and override them in C as necessary.  Does that make sense, or am I missing something?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker , I explain, suppose there is a temperature sensor, when that gets disconnected from machine, class B draws a content blocker image on the whole area of Qwidget that it owns, I can monitor sensor connect /disconnect and suppose C's fun. OnDisconnect() gets called, I will call B::OnDisconnect(), B will draw blocker image on its own Qwidget, not on the one which is owned by C

Comment: @Sumit I'm sorry I don't follow.  Is the idea that a B and a C must coexist and perform similar but different functions at different times, or are you trying to code your own C as an extension of B, and you will use C in place of all B?

Comment: I think the OP wants to use `C` to provide a visualization for `B`

Comment: "I don't have source of B" I doubt that. It's next to impossible to use Qt-based binary libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose there is a temperature sensor, when that gets disconnected from machine, class `B` draws a content blocker image on the whole area of `QWidget` that it owns, I can monitor sensor connect /disconnect and suppose `C`'s fun. `OnDisconnect()` gets called, I will call `B::OnDisconnect()`, `B` will draw blocker image on its own `QWidget`, not on the one which is owned by `C`.

This has everything to do with C++'s rather inflexible method implementation inheritance when compared e.g. to the Common LISP Object System.

Since `B`'s obscuration is always meant to be on top of `B`'s contents, what you effectively need is for `B` to provide an overlay that draws on top of its contents, even if `paintEvent` is overriden in derived classes.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367454/1329652) for a simple example, or [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386886/1329652) for an overlay with blur graphical effect.

This is fairly easy to accomplish by having `B` add an optional overlay widget to itself.

Example:

```
class OverlayWidget; // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367454/1329652    

class ObscureOverlay : public OverlayWidget
{
public:
  ObscureOverlay(QWidget * parent = {}) : OverlayWidget{parent} {}
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
    QPainter p{this};
    p.fillRect(rect(), {Qt::black});
  }
};

class A : public QWidget {
  ...
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override { ... }
};

class B : public A {
  ...
  ObscureOverlay m_obscure{this};
public:
  B() {
    m_obscure.hide();
  }
  Q_SLOT void OnDisconnect() {
    m_obscure.show();
    ...
  }
};

class C : public B {
  ...
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) override {
    B::paintEvent(event);
    ...
  }
};
```

If you don't have the source code to `B`, you can add the overlay to `C`, replicating original `B`'s functionality when obscured. All of Qt's slots are effectively virtual, so if you pass a `C` to someone expecting `B` and connecting to its `OnDisconnect` slot, it will be `C`'s slot that will get invoked.

```
class C : public B {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  ObscureOverlay m_obscure{this};
public:
  explicit C(QWidget * parent = {}) : B{parent} {
    m_obscure.hide();
  }
  Q_SLOT void OnDisconnect() { // slots are effectively virtual
    m_obscure.show();
    B::OnDisconnect();
  }
protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) override {
    B::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter p{this};
    ...
  }
};
```