# Strange behavior of margins for Qt controls

Tags: qt, qt5.2

I have just started using Qt (5.3) and encountered the fact that some controls appears with margins which I cannot control.

First, I tried to put QLabel and QPushButton right inside QMainWindow

```
window = new QMainWindow;
label = new QLabel( title, window );
```

In this case label appears with a margin of 12 pixels at the top (see picture).
QPushButton appears with 1 pixel top & left margins.
But if I insert QFrame with a border, it appears without any margin.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsll7.jpg]

So the margins seem to be attributes of QLabel and QPushButton.
BUT:

When I tried to add extra QFrame between windows and controls:

```
window = new QMainWindow;
frame = new QFrame(window );
label = new QLabel( title, frame);
```

I had got different picture:
QLabels top margin had shortened to 1 pixel
QPushButton 1 pixel margins remained intact, but the height of the button had changed

I have tried:
setStyleSheet( "padding:0px" )
and
setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 )

for all elements, but without any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `QMainWindow` class isn't designed to have widgets added to it directly. Whatever results you see are due to this fact.

The "margins" that you see are not really margins. Since a `QLabel` is a `QFrame`, you can enable its frame to see that it has no margin - merely the text is offset from the edge, and that's by design. You can similarly overlay a same-size translucent rectangle on a `QPushButton` to see that there is also no margin, merely the styling adds its own platform-specific margin. Do not mistake the platform styling mechanism for the style sheets: they are two separate mechanisms and mostly exclusive, with the use of the latter disabling the effects of the former, with few exceptions. For example, the stylesheet spacing/margins/padding is additive to whatever the platform style mandates.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201908/1329652) for an example of how to show overlays on any widget without subclassing.

Comment: What kind of widget should I use to add controls? I need to specify exact position of a control within its parent, like in Win32. I do not need arrangement provided by a layout.

Comment: @BorisL `QWidget`. Be aware that for controls that users can interact with, specifying fixed position is rather pointless since those controls *cannot* have arbitrary sizes. When you forcibly resize some of their dimensions (say vertical dimension of a button), they'll not look like native controls anymore, since the native controls have certain sizes that are fixed. So this only makes sense if you're using stylesheets to disable platform styles.