# How to draw a line over widget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, paintevent

I have a mainwindow and more than two widget on mainwindow. I wanna draw lines on the whole mainwindow and when the line should be over the widgets not behind these widgets. I've tried overwrite paintevent function of mainwindow and draw a line directly but the line is behind widgets.
What should I do?

Comment: You need to draw (continue) the line on the widgets too.

Comment: @vahancho But paintevent function of my widgets have been used, how could I draw lines on the widgets?

Comment: In the same way: override the paint event for **each** widget. You said, that you override paint event function of the main window only.

Comment: Well, if I've overridden  paint event function of some widgets, what could I do?

Comment: I don't understand your need exactly, but it's so easy to make a GUI with line or polygon, path, circle, etc. with Qt Graphics View framework ! Have you an example image with your need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an overlay widget, i.e. a widget that covers the area of your main widget, but is above it. Then you implement `paintEvent()` in that overlay widget. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199863/draw-rectangular-overlay-on-qwidget-at-click) for more details.