# How to draw a line on a child widget instead of the parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm trying to draw a line (and some other primitives) on a QWidget.  That QWidget is physically "on top of" another widget with a picture in it.  I want to draw lines and circles over a picture.

I know how to draw a line already.  I can do that with this code:

```
bool MySpecialWidget::eventFilter( QObject* watched, QEvent* event )
{
    if (watched == this && event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);

        painter.translate(50, 50);

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 12));
        painter.setBrush(Qt::BrushStyle::SolidPattern);
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    return false;
}
```

But what I really want to do is position a widget to hold a picture, then position a widget over it to hold the lines.  Like this:

```
MySpecialWidget::MySpecialWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QRect position = QRect(30, 50, 600, 600);

    pictureBox = new QLabel(parent);
    pictureBox->setGeometry(position);
    pictureBox->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/main/graphics/MyPicture.png")));
    pictureBox->setScaledContents(true);

    drawnElements = new QWidget(parent);
    drawnElements->setGeometry(position);
    drawnElements->raise();

    this->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

Then to draw the lines and primitives, I want to do it like this:

```
bool MySpecialWidget::eventFilter( QObject* watched, QEvent* event )
{
    if (watched == this && event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        QPainter painter(drawnElements);

        painter.translate(50, 50);

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 12));
        painter.setBrush(Qt::BrushStyle::SolidPattern);
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    return false;
}
```

But this doesn't work.  Nothing is drawn.  Blank.

The problem is the line that reads `QPainter painter(drawnElements);`

If I say `QPainter painter(this);`, it draws something, but it's not on the child widget, it's on the parent widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is the line that reads `QPainter painter(drawnElements);`

Of course. You need to be watching the **target** widget instead and catch its paint event. To control the order of drawing, you should explicitly deliver the event to the target as well.

```
bool MySpecialWidget::eventFilter( QObject* watched, QEvent* event )
{
    //         *** vvvvvvvvvvvvv *** (A)
    if (watched == drawnElements && event->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        // Let the target draw itself first.
        watched->event(event);
        // Then overlay our content on it.
        //           *** vvvvvvvvvvvvv *** (B) - must match (A)!
        QPainter painter(drawnElements);
        painter.translate(50, 50);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 12));
        painter.setBrush(Qt::BrushStyle::SolidPattern);
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
        return true; // The event is already handled.
    }
    return false;
}

MySpecialWidget::MySpecialWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    //...
    drawnElements->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

Feel free to also consider using an [overlay widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201908/1329652).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear on the subject:

> Each widget performs all painting operations from within its
>   paintEvent() function. This is called whenever the widget needs to be
>   redrawn, either as a result of some external change or when requested
>   by the application.

You should only draw on a widget from its paint event, and you should only draw on that particular widget.