# How to draw shape over a widget in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to draw a shape over a widget and from what I understand you can do this by overriding the `paintEvent()` method. However, when I do so, the shape is rendered at the back. How can I render the shape in front?
I'm using pyqt5 and my test code is:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen,QBrush,QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout,QPushButton
import sys

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Hello World')
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green))
        brush = QBrush(QColor(0,0,255,255))
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRect(0,0,50,50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainscreen = MyWidget()
    mainscreen.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "at the front"? Can you add a mockup picture showing the desired result?

Comment: @S.Monteleone thanks for the reply, I have uploaded a sample image

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. You want to draw the red square on top of all the widgets. Then the answer by @BenjaminT is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt5: QPainter overlay QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022786/pyqt5-qpainter-overlay-qwidget)

Answer (score 3):

Qt widgets are drawn from parent to children.
That means that `MyWidget` paints itself (by calling `paintEvent()`) before the `QPushButton` paints itself.

One possible solution is to create a widget to draw the rectangle and make it a sibling of `QPushButton` (i.e child of `MyWidget`). You can then decide of the rendering order of `QPushButton` and `RectangleWidget` by using `QWidget::stackUnder()`, `QWidget::raise()` or `QWidget::lower()`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. The `QWidget::lower()` doesn't seem to work (or more probably I just messed up the heirarchies).

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a Python version of a common problem: how to overlay stuff over the widgets. I have a series of overlay-related answers: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386886/1329652), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367454/1329652), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201908/1329652).

The third answer, recast in Python:

```
# https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/python-overlay-49920532
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Overlay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

    def paintEvent(self, event) {
        QPainter(self).fillrect(self.rect(), QColor(80, 80, 255, 128))

class Filter(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.m_overlay = None
        self.m_overlayOn = None

    def eventFilter(self, w, event):
        if w.isWidgetType():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if not m_overlay:
                    m_overlay = Overlay(w.parentWidget());
                    m_overlay.setGeometry(w.geometry());
                    m_overlayOn = w;
                    m_overlay.show();
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
                if m_overlay and m_overlayOn is w:
                    m_overlay.setGeometry(w.geometry());
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    filter = Filter()
    window = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout(window);
    for text in ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]:
        label = QLabel(text)
        label.installEventFilter(filter)
        layout.addWidget(label)
    window.setMinimumSize(300, 250)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried both solutions and they both work for me.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica The python solution mentioned in this answer is very much buggy.

Comment: @Raj I don't quite know how such simple code can be "buggy" - it'll either work or it won't. If there are any particular problems you have, share a gist link to a reproducer and I'll take a look. Given that it is a direct translation of the C++ code, then I'd expect both to be "buggy".