# QLabel overlay png over gif

Tags: qt, png, overlay, gif, qlabel

I have a QLabel and I can set a gif to animate as qmovie or a png to show as qpixmap.
What I want to do is to animate the gif and put a png over it.
Both images have transparent background. The gif is animated "loading circle", png is a "check" icon.

The code below is displaying the last one only.

```
#define MOOD_RESULT ":/mood/mood_result.gif"
#define MOOD_SUCCESS ":/mood/mood_success.png"

ui->moodicon->setPixmap(QPixmap(MOOD_SUCCESS));

QMovie *movie = new QMovie(MOOD_RESULT);
ui->moodicon->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

I hope a Qt guru can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are workable ideas:

1. Combine the images manually by playing the movie one-by-one into a pixmap, then overpainting the static image, and setting the result on the label.
2. Derive from `QLabel`, overload `paintEvent`, and overpaint the static image after calling `QLabel::paintEvent`.
3. [Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201908/1329652) another label on top of the one with the movie.